# ping in command prompt using computer name says "destination host unreachable" but it works properly when I use Ip Address to ping

Tags: networking, ip, ping

just new to stackoverflow. I have an issue with regards to using "ping" command in my PC's command prompt. I am using windows 7 OS.

Whenever I issue a "ping VMSTBOX" command in my cmd it returns "destination host unreachable". VMSTBOX is my Computer Name. However when I use "ping 192.168.111.223" which is my IP address in in my **Local Area Connection-->Properties-->TCP/IPv4** . it works just fine. They are basically just the same machine but why doesnt it work when i use my computer name?

I triple checked everything to make sure there are no typos in the inputs or names used but to no avail. I can't post a screenshot since I need 10 points to be able to post an image.

Any help or suggestions to fixing this would be a great help Thanks!

Comment: use ipconfig/all to make sure you got the host name right,

Comment: I did and as I said in the post , I triple checked all the names to make sure it is the correct ones

Comment: Your symptoms mean that your computer does not know how to resolve names. This is usually done by a DNS (domain name service) which is usually done (or at least passed through) by the machine that you are connected to, your router - the same machine that provides you with the IP address in the first place (=DHCP server). Ask your network admin to properly configure your router.

Comment: Can you ping other machines by name?

Comment: cylua2's answer did the trick. Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click Start > All Programs > Accessories.
2. Right-click Notepad and select Run as administrator.
3. Click Continue on the Windows needs your permission UAC window.
4. When Notepad opens, click File > Open.
5. In the File name field, type C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.
6. Click Open.
7. Add the Line `192.168.111.223 VMSTBOX`
8. Click File > Save to save your changes.

The above steps should allows you to ping yourself using the name VMSTBOX with the ip address 192.168.11.223, change 192.168.111.223 to local ip 127.0.0.1 if you just want it to be able to ping yourself.

Comment: There are also other computers connected to it which also has the same scenario where they can ping my computer using the IP address but not the using my computer name. But thanks will try your suggestion and get back to you on this.

Comment: @Adrian if the above doesn't work, just try disable your firewall entirely and see whether that works.

Comment: Thanks your answer solved my problem! Cheers